# Следует ли ставить запятую перед словом "как"?

Tags: запятые

> И все же мы, как общественная организация, кардинальным образом
> отличаемся от других групп.

Нужны ли запятые перед союзом "как" и после слова "организация"? Мне кажется, что запятые не нужны.

Answer (score 1):

`И все же мы, как общественная организация, кардинальным образом отличаемся от других групп.` =  `И все же мы, поскольку общественная организация, кардинальным образом отличаемся от других групп.`

Но

`И все же мы как общественная организация кардинальным образом отличаемся от других групп.` = `И все же мы именно в качестве общественной организации кардинальным образом отличаемся от других групп.`

Сравните также:

```
Я, как старший, приказал им сдаться. // Приказал, потому что был старший
```

и

```
Я как старший приказал им сдаться. // Приказал в качестве старшего. Потому что только старший мог отдавать такие приказы
```

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, перед относительным местоимением "как" ставится запятая, если оно образует относительное придаточное предложение. Источник – Википедия.

```
ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Относительное_местоимение
```

Answer (score 0):

Сравнительный оборот со значением «в качестве» обособляется, если только находится не под ударением.
Он, как психолог, отлично все понимал.
Он прибыл туда как психолог.
Он прибыл туда как главнокомандующий.
И все же мы, как общественная организация, кардинальным образом отличаемся от других групп.